# Find Strong Authentication in Azure Powershell / Azure Cli

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-resource-manager

I am looking for Get-MsolUserByStrongAuthentication equivalent for Azure Powershell / Azure Cli

Comment: the MSonline module is for azure AD? https://onlinehelp.coveo.com/en/ces/7.0/administrator/installing_the_windows_azure_ad_module_for_windows_powershell.htm

Answer (score 0):

The Windows Azure Active Directory Module for Windows PowerShell cmdlets can be used to accomplish many Windows Azure AD tenant-based administrative tasks such as user management, domain management and for configuring single sign-on

Install the Windows Azure Active Directory Module for Windows PowerShell

Connect to Windows Azure AD by running the PowerShell command `import-module MSOnline`

then you are good to proceed.

Hope it helps.